# Swift embeded UIView in container of Main UIViewController - how to transition from 1 embeded UIView to the next embeded UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I can successfully embed the first UIView in the container by simply dragging the container to the new UIView however to add the transition view, I am not able to replace the current embed view with a new view on key enter event.

Here are my codes for this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var overlayView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var logoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var overlayUIView: UIView!

private var embeddedViewController: ViewController!
private var birthdayPickerController: BirthdayPickerController!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    self.birthdayPickerController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("birthdayPickerController") as! BirthdayPickerController

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "lasvegas.jpg")!)

    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)

    self.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext

    logoImage.image = UIImage(named: "philia");

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    self.embeddedViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as! ViewController


    self.embeddedViewController.setOverlayUIView(overlayUIView)
}



let viewControllerIdentifiers = ["viewController", "birthdayPickerController"]  // storyboard identifiers for the child view controllers

/*
@IBAction func didChangeValue(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let newController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]))! as UIViewController

    let oldController = childViewControllers.last! as UIViewController

    oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    addChildViewController(newController)
    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame

    transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        // nothing needed here
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
            newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    })
}
*/
}


import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

/*
 * Reference to the container in MainViewController
 * This is where all views are rendered
 */
private var overlayUIView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var backgroundImageView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var anotherTextLabel: UITextView!

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

func setOverlayUIView(overlayView: UIView) {
    overlayUIView = overlayView
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    onEnter(textField)
    return false
}

@IBAction func onEnter(sender: UITextField) {
    let msgEntered = textField.text

    anotherTextLabel.text = "Hi \(msgEntered!)!"


    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let birthdayPickerController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("birthdayPickerController") as! BirthdayPickerController

    birthdayPickerController.name = textField.text!

    overlayUIView.willRemoveSubview(self.view)
    overlayUIView.addSubview(birthdayPickerController.view)

    /*
    self.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)



self.parentViewController?.addChildViewController(birthdayPickerController)

    birthdayPickerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

    transitionFromViewController(self, toViewController: birthdayPickerController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> Void in}, completion: {(finished) -> Void in
            self.removeFromParentViewController()
            birthdayPickerController.didMoveToParentViewController(self.parentViewController)
    })
*/

        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdViewController, animated: true)

        //self.parentViewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("birthdayPickerController", sender: self)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0).CGColor

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)

    self.textField.delegate = self;

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

/*
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "birthdayPickerController" {
        let birthdayPickerController = segue.destinationViewController as! BirthdayPickerController

        birthdayPickerController.name = textField.text!
    }
}
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.  I used a delegate to pass the parent to the embedded controllers and had the child controllers make a callback to the parent with the new controller class where the parent class will then swap out the old controller for the new controller.